# Missing method call for verify(mock), but there is one?

Tags: java, mockito, jukito

## Introduction

I'm attempting to make a test which verifies (using Mockito v1.9.5's `verify`) that a method with signature `deinit()` in an interface `Bar` is called after execution of a pass-through `Foo.deinit()`, and I'm hitting an error I really don't understand.

Here's the `FooTest.java` which I'm attempting to run:

```
@RunWith(JukitoRunner.class)
public class FooTest {
    @Inject
    private Foo foo;
    @Inject
    private Bar bar;

    public static class TestModule extends JukitoModule {
        @Override
        protected void configureTest() {
            bind(Foo.class).to(FooImpl.class);
            bind(Bar.class).to(BarImpl.class);
            bindSpy(BarImpl.class);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeinit() {
        foo.init(mock(Baz.class));
        foo.deinit();
        verify(bar).deinit();
    }

    @After
    public void validate() {
        validateMockitoUsage(); //line YY
    }
}
```

When running this, `testDeinit()` fails with the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException:
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
  -> at redacted.impl.BarImpl.deinit(BarImpl.java:XX)
  
Example of correct verification:
  verify(mock).doSomething()
  
Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods. 
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified. 

at redacted.impl.FooTest.validate(FooTest.java:YY)
at org.jukito.InjectedStatement.evaluate(InjectedStatement.java:96)
at org.jukito.InjectedAfterStatements.evaluate(InjectedAfterStatements.java:58)
at org.jukito.jukitoRunner.run(JukitoRunner.java:197)
```

Which I haven't been able to extract much useful information from. It seems almost as if the error complains that  `verify(bar).deinit()` might as well not have a `.deinit()` off the end, and I can remove that portion and get an identical error.  The example provided in the error message is especially frustrating, as it appears almost identical to my use of `verify`.

## Details

Here's my `BarImpl.java`

```
public class BarImpl implements Bar {
    private final Qux qux;
    private final Quux quux;

    @Inject
    public BarImpl(final Qux qux, final Quux quux) {
        this.qux = qux;
        this.quux = quux;
    }

    @Override
    private final void init(Baz baz) {
        quux.init(this);
        qux.init();
    }

    @Override
    public final void deinit() {
        qux.deinit();  //line XX
    }
}
```

I'm still unclear how the `qux.deinit()` causes failure here. Here's my `FooImpl.java`:

```
class FooImpl implements Foo {
    private final Bar bar;

    @Inject
    public FooImpl(final Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Baz baz) {
        bar.init(baz);
    }

    @Override
    public void deinit() {
        bar.deinit(); 
    }
}
```

## Question

*What's causing the UnfinishedVerificationException and how can it be fixed?*

I'm a Mockito newb so it's very likely I've missed something fundamental. Please let me know if there's more information I can provide. Sorry if this has been answered already and I've misunderstood answers here on SO.

Comment: If only all low rep users could write questions like this, the world would be a perfect place. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually your problem is in the error message:

> Also, this error might show up because you verify either of:
>   **final**/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.  Those methods *cannot* be
>   stubbed/verified.

Indeed you try to implicitly verify calls to `BarImpl#deinit` which is a **`final`** method and `Mockio` doesn't support `final` method mocking as explained [into the doc](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#what-are-the-limitations-of-mockito). If you want to verify it you need either to remove the keyword `final` from the declaration of `BarImpl#deinit` or use [Powermock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) instead.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was getting this because I was trying to do verify() on a spy (rather than a mock). I was doing:

```
mySpy = Mockito.spy(<<constructor>>);
```

I had to do this instead:

```
mySpy = mock(MyClass.class, delegatesTo(<<constructor>>)
```