# Missing method call for verify(mock) here. How to test dynamic value

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I want to verify that someMethod is being called once when I call doSomething(). Within doSomething() the currentTimeMillis() is being called and this value will not be exactly the same. How can I test this?

Currently I get this error message:

*org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException:

Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at myapplication.SomeLoginClassTest.trackDoSomething handles values(SomeLoginClassTest.kt:24)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()*

```
class SomeLoginClassTest {

    @get:Rule
    val mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule()

    @Mock
    lateinit var someClass: SomeClass

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var someLoginClass: SomeLoginClass

    @Test
    fun `trackDoSomething handles values`() {
        someLoginClass.doSomething()
        Mockito.verify(someClass).someMethod(System.currentTimeMillis())
    }
}

    open class SomeLoginClass @Inject constructor(private val someClass: SomeClass) {

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    fun doSomething() {
        val elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        someClass.someMethod(elapsedTime)
    }
}

open class SomeClass {

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public fun someMethod(elapsedTime: Long) {
        var elapsed = Random().longs()
    }
}
```

Build.gradle:

```
// Dagger
api "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13"

api "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.13"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.13"

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.18.3'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

// Dependencies for Android unit tests
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.18.3"
androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.18.3"
androidTestImplementation "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0"
```

I've tried this:

[Missing method call for verify(mock), but there is one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350009/missing-method-call-for-verifymock-but-there-is-one)

[Mockito gives UnfinishedVerificationException when it seems OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904584/mockito-gives-unfinishedverificationexception-when-it-seems-ok/31085466)

Comment: Instead of specifying the exact long value, try using anyLong(). If you care about the value, then you need to wrap currentTimeMillis in some other class you can control.

Comment: I don't care and I get the error: UnfinishedVerificationException. Missing method call for verify(mock) here.

Answer (score 0):

`Mockito.verify(someClass).someMethod(System.currentTimeMillis())`

is the incorrect syntax for verification it should be

`Mockito.verify(someClass).someMethod(Mockito.eq(System.currentTimeMillis()))`

and as the comment that [AutonomousApps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2740621/autonomousapps) suggested it should be

`Mockito.verify(someClass).someMethod(Mockito.anyLong())`

Comment: can you explain what you don't care about?